# Sending data to another site in workflow permission

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, web-services

What permission is required for a user who is running the workflow, to send data to another site collection through: `call web service`.

Does the user have to have permission on the other site collection? Or the call web service action in SharePoint Designer will use the workflow author permissions for it?

Comment: 2013 or 2010 workflow engine?

Comment: 2013 workflow engine

Answer (score 1):

Can this be accomplished with an impersonation step?  Then the user wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

User would require permission on other site, because it is called with the credentials of the author. 
The level of permission required will depend on what you want to do with web service.

You can try calling the service in app step, maybe it will work but i'm not sure.